# WCF listen to Service Bus

Tags: wcf, azure

I’m new to WCF and are having problems by finding the solution to my problem.
I have WCF set up that handles some logic (simple database handling).
I then have a web page (ASP.NET) that gets it data from WCF (and also sends it data to WCF).
Now I’m trying to use an Azure Service Bus to send data to WCF. It works fine when I go through the ASP.NET website. It works like this:
1, Client application sends data to Service Bus.
2, ASP.NET Webpage reads data from Service Bus.
3, ASP.NET Sends data to WCF.
4, WCF updates the database.
Everything works fine.
But, I would like the WCF to constantly listen to the Service Bus.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario you have 2 options:

- Use the WCF endpoint of the Service Bus Queues: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/10/07/using-service-bus-queues-with-wcf.aspx
- Use the service bus relay: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-relay/

Depending on your scenario you'll use one of these options. The first scenario uses queueing. If your WCF service should be unavailable for any reason your client will still keep working (messages are delivered to the queue and picked up by the WCF service whenever available).

The second scenario will create a bridge between your client and a WCF service (could be on premises, in an other data center, ...). Since it's a direct connection you can receive a response. But keep in mind, if your WCF service is offline, your client will receive an exception and you'll need to handle that.